# How to convert non string type data to string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Edit** **I don't want to convert datetime to date, there are several other such words without quotes, I just need to convert word without quotes to string.**

I am retrieving some data from database and processing it. I am getting error in ast.literal eval as it is not getting data in correct format. For example see the data

> 'Starlink', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0), datetime.date(2020,
> 10, 23), 'starlink'

This is exactly how I am getting it without quotes for datetime word. The date time object is inserted due to mistake. Now how to convert datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0) to  string. Eventually I need to convert all these comma separated word to a list. But I cannot split with (,) because there are some sentences which consists of (,)comma
See the code

## so previous meta data will be 'Starlink', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0), datetime.date(2020, 10, 23), 'starlink' as a row from databse

```
previous_meta_data = previous_meta_data.lstrip(' ')
previous_meta_data = previous_meta_data.rstrip(' ')
#previous_meta_data = previous_meta_data[1:-1]
#print(previous_meta_data)
previous_meta_data = re.sub("'\s*([^']*?)\s*'", r"'\1'", previous_meta_data)
#previous_meta_data = previous_meta_data.replace('\\','')
#print(type(previous_meta_data))
import ast
import json
previous_meta_data =ast.literal_eval(previous_meta_data)
```

Can someone help me with answer ?

Comment: No that is not important I just need to convert any such data without quotes to string like datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0).strftime should be a string """  datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0).strftime """  I don;t want to convert it to date @Ch3steR

Comment: `repr(datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0))` gives `'datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0)'` is this what you  are looking for?

Comment: @Ch3steR correct, but ast.literal is not considering it as a string.

Comment: @Pritish you can convert the data to string using `str()`. `data = 'Starlink', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0), datetime.date(2020, 10, 23), 'starlink'` and use: `str(data)`

Comment: I already did that, but it still won't treat datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0) separately as a string. @DavidDr90

Comment: @Pritish I think the `''` in some words are causing the porblem... can we remove them?

Comment: You mean 'Starlink' so ending and starting quote ? @DavidDr90

Comment: @Pritish exactly!

Comment: @DavidDr90 let me check if I can do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert only date to string. Then -

Convert datetime to date then that to string

```
x = x.date()
x.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

otherwise try:

```
x.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M")
```

or you can also check `str(x)`

You can also change format of datetime.

Comment: Hi please see the edit, I have mentioned I don't want to convert date, I want the whole thing as a string like """datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 0, 0).strftime """ but ast.literal.eval doesn not treat it as a proper string